# What should I change in my code to make textfield in cell not to be nil after dismiss VC

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitextfield, tableview

Community!

I have some issue.

code:

```
protocol CellDelegate: class { }

class Cell: UITableViewCell {

.....
   @IBOutlet weak var valueTextField: UITextField!

   weak var delegate: CellDelegate?
.....
}
```

`didSelectRowAt indexPath` presents my ContainerView by overFullScreen, where I have:

```
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {

.....

  @IBOutlet private weak var fromTextField: UITextField!

  @IBOutlet private weak var toTextField: UITextField!

  @IBAction private func performChange(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let from = Int(fromTextField.text!), let to = Int(toTextField.text!) {
          let cell = Cell()
          cell.delegate = self
          cell.valueTextField = "\(from) - \(to)"
          self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
     }
   }
.....
}

extension ContainerViewController: CellDelegate { }
```

printDebug tells me that `performChange` sending my data well to other class, but cell.valueTextField is being nil when ContainerViewController dismiss and app crash

I know that I can make valueTextField.text = "1 - 5" //example `from 1 to 5`
with help of alert, but I need to make it with other viewController.

Please help me

Comment: It does not work, Add protocol delegate on your ContainerViewController as well as on which controller where you want to update the data that comes from ContainerViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use

```
let cell = Cell()
```

but instead add a delegate to the previous vc when you present the containervc (inside `didSelectRowAt`) and send the data before the dismiss , then change the array model of the table and finally refresh the table

Comment: Thank a lot! But to init my delegate I made him static xD.. and in didSelect i said "ContainerVC.delegate = self" it's ok?